# Use Like operator on a loop on dropdown menu

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, dropdown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3xS.png I have 13 dropdown menues. The for loop works(Checks to make sure I don't select the same device and number more than once). Trying to solve the If statements at the end, validating if when I select device A, B or "channel not available" that the two text inputs have values in them. 1) If device A is selected, verify that a number is provided in first text input box.
2) If device B is selected, verify that a number is provided for the second text input box. 3) Verify that at least a number is provided for either device a or b text input box. Currently, my messages are popping up, but when I click the Next button, nothing happens? Even if I enter values in the text input and click next, nothing seems to be happening. I figured it is the structure of my If statements, need some help creating the validation. Any thoughts?

```
If (HTSelection.DeviceDropDown1.List(0)) <> Empty Then
        
    Else
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 1"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 2"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 3"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 4"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 5"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 6"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 7"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 8"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 1"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 2"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 3"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 4"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 5"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 6"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 7"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 8"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Channel_Not_Available"
    End If
    End Sub

Private Sub HTNextButton_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    DDi = 1
    DDj = 1
    Numberflag = 0
    DeviceFlagA = 0
    DeviceFlagB = 0
    For DDi = 1 To 13
        Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDi)
        If Device = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
        ElseIf Device = "Select Device" Then
            MsgBox "Please select Number channel for Device" & DDi, vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit For
        Else
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device A") Then
                DeviceFlagA = 1
            End If
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device B") Then
                DeviceFlagB = 1
            End If
                
            For DDj = 1 To 13
            
                If DDi <> DDj Then
                    Device1 = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDj)
                    If Device1 = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
                    Else
                        If Device = Device1 Then
                            MsgBox "Please select different number for Device" & DDj, vbCritical, "Error"
                            Numberflag = Numberflag + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
    End If
            Next
            If Numberflag >= 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next

        If DeviceFlagA = 1 Then
         If HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text <> Empty Then
          Else
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number for device A", vbCritical, "Error"
            End If

        If DeviceFlagB = 1 Then
         If HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB.Text <> Empty Then
          Else
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number for device B", vbCritical, "Error"
            End If

        If Numberflag = 0 Then
         If (HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text <> Empty Or HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB <> Empty) Then
            Number = HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text
            Numberb = HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB.Text
              Set clientNumber = CreateObject("Device.usb")
              Set clientNumberb = CreateObject("Deviceb.usb")
            End If
            Me.Hide
            Chart.Show

            Else
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number", vbCritical, "Error"
            End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use LIKE with wildcard? Also, please explain what isn't working with your code. And is this Excel/Access? Often useful to add the Application to the tag list.

Comment: I switched to the LIKE. However, I need help with the structure of the loop. When I try to compile, I get a "Block If without End If" error.

Comment: Hi, indent your code properly and look for the missing End If (s)

Comment: Figured out the End If situation. Thank you. Fixed up top as well. Now to get the MsgBox to actually pop up when condition is met.

Comment: No worries there :-) You should still [edit] to add in what isn't working with your code. I think there are still some problems including identation problems howver. Look at where your _End Sub_ is. Compare with https://pastebin.com/mGZ21W4P

Comment: I fixed the End Sub part for you, to clarify. However, yes, the for isn't working 100%. When I click the next button, all three messages pop up in a row. Not sure why "Please enter address for Device A" , "Device B" pop up when I haven't even selected a Device A or B from the dropdown list to begin with.

Comment: @QHarr Got the for loop running, changed a lot of code. Still struggling with the If statements at the end. When I click next, nothing happens.

Comment: That On Error Resume Next will just mask any errors. It should be used sparingly and switched off with On Error GoTo 0  as soon as possible. Remove the On Error Resume Next and are there any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your Sub HTNextButton_Click() and made some corrections in the if-then-else statements. Please check my comments as I don't know all your requirements and conditions.

```
Private Sub HTNextButton_Click()
    Dim Numberflag As Boolean
    
'    On Error Resume Next
    
' not required
'    DDi = 1
'    DDj = 1

    Numberflag = False
    DeviceFlagA = 0
    DeviceFlagB = 0
    
    For DDi = 1 To 13
        Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDi)
        
        If Device = "Select Device" Then
            MsgBox "Please select Number channel for Device" & DDi, vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit For
        End If
        
        If Device = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
' Do nothing (?)
        Else
       
' Determine if it is Device A or B
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device A") Then
                DeviceFlagA = 1
            End If
            
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device B") Then
                DeviceFlagB = 1
            End If
                
' Check that the selection is not duplicate
            For DDj = 1 To 13
                If DDi <> DDj Then
                    Device1 = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDj)
' The case of Device1 = "Channel_Not_Available" is also covered with the comparison
' as we should never get here with Device = "Channel_Not_Available"
                    
' If duplicate entry found, leave the for-next loop DDj
                    If Device = Device1 Then
                        MsgBox "Please select different number for Device" & DDj, vbCritical, "Error"
                        Numberflag = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next DDj
            
' if any of the entries is duplicate, leave the for-next loop DDi
            If Numberflag Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next DDi

' Do you need to execute the operations for "DeviceFlag" if Numberflag =True? What happens in case of "Select Device"?

    If DeviceFlagA = 1 Then
        If HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number for device A", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
            Number = HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text
        End If

    End If
    
    If DeviceFlagB = 1 Then
        If HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number for device B", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
            Numberb = HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB.Text
        End If
    End If

    If Numberflag = False Then
' I guess you only want those objects where the flag is set. consider moving them into the if statements above
        If DeviceFlagA = 1 Then
           Set clientNumber = CreateObject("Device.usb")
        End If
        
        If DeviceFlagB = 1 Then
            Set clientNumberb = CreateObject("Deviceb.usb")
        End If
        Me.Hide
        Chart.Show
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter valid number", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the support! I tested this out and it works. I am going to add changes to my code as well because I came up with a solution too.

Comment: welcome! If you don't need any action in the "Channel not available" clause then you can also switch the condition to "<>" and remove the "else".

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer yet but an indicator where to investigate further. I have taken your "FOR" construct and structured it so that you can see where a block starts and where it ends. From there you can see that in the part of the code you provided, almost all "End If" as well as the "Next Hti" is missing. I suppose they are there, but if not then it is clear where the error comes from.

```
For Hti = 1 To 13
' If you want to check 2 dropdowns you must assign them to 2 different variables
    Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown")
' Device is a Control object, so you will need Device.Name or Device.ItemsSelected depending what you want to check
' instead of "like" you can also use Instr for searching a string in another
    If Device.ItemsSelected Like "*Device A*" And DeviceSAInput = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please enter address for Device A"
    End If

    If Device.ItemsSelected Like "*Device B*" And DeviceSAInputB = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please enter address for Device B"
        Exit For
    End If

' This part is missing in the code
Next Hti
```

Please check again your code. Ideally provide the complete function. Format the code like my fragment and use

```
Option Explicit
```

To find any undefined variable.

Then I can have another look on the issue.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the missing End If. The application compiles and runs. However, when I press the "Next" button, my MsgBox don't pop up. DeviceSAinput and DeviceSAInputB are the two text inputs at the bottom of my picture.

Comment: Reviewing the code once again, I see that you don't need the first check at all. It is fully sufficient if you test for each individual dropdown and make sure that the corresponding hex field must be filled. I will provide an update in a couple of minutes

Comment: Yes and I realized I was saying <> Empty instead of = Empty! Big difference.

Comment: try this ```If Instr(1, Device.ItemSelected, "Device A") And DeviceSAInput = "" Then```

Comment: The loop is a little funky. For instance, if i don't select anything and all the drop downs say "Channel Not Available", the MsgBox displays the correct message as above. Then another message box comes up saying "Please enter address for Device A" and after I click okay, same for Device B message, then it exits. It also repeats those messages 13 times...

Comment: It does not repeat 13 times, I took out the "Exit For". I tried putting "Exit For" on the other two checks (CNAvailable & Device A), however it continues to the next page when I click "Ok" on MsgBox. I want the message to pop up and then have the user fix it after they click "Ok". I know I am close. Also, it still shows Device A empty / Device B empty even if I haven't selected a Device A or B from the drop down..

Comment: you can add "instr > 0" which means that it definitely found something. In another thread I read that "= Empty" is treacherous. Better use "". And It should definitely not repeat 13 times when you exit the loop after "Device B". For debugging you can use ```Debug.print xxx```. Put that in your code where you want to see what's in the variables.

Comment: Still having a little issue with messages popping up, regardless if condition is met or not. Then when I click "Ok", the application doesn't take me back to fix it, it continues to the next screen, which I don't want to have happen. You can see my response above to @QHarr

Comment: have you tried to debug print the variable contents? If you walk throught the code step by step (using F8) you can follow each individual value and check the behavior in the condition clause. And replacing the <>empty with "" might also help.

Comment: I did the debug. For some reason, HTi properly increments (1 to 13) and spits out the messages. However, Device stays at "Empty", DeviceSAInput & DeviceSAInputB stay Empty. By default, I have the dropdown menu set to "Channel Not Available", so Device should be "Channel Not Available" at start, but it doesn't even show that. It stays at Empty.

Comment: as mentioned before, please replace "Empty" with "". Moreover, are you certain that you have connected the variables DeviceSAInput and DeviceSAInputB to the right control? Also I guess it should read ``` Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown1") ```

Comment: I changed the code a lot. For loop works great, added flags for Device A and B, using Instr. I stepped through with Debug, I know the flags are going to 1 when I select certain devices. Just need help with If statements and validation. The next button isn't clicking. Thanks

Comment: Try the following: ``` If (HTSelection.DeviceSAInput.Text <> "" Or HTSelection.DeviceSAInputB <> "") Then ```. And what do you mean with "The next button isn't clicking"? In order to make it work, the button and the routine must have the same name. If you name a button "Select_my_Choice", then the click event must have the name "Select_my_Choice_Click()". Otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: When I click the Next button, I don't set the clients and jump to the next page. Something is wrong with my structure of Ifs and End Ifs.